# No improvement in using openmp in MATLAB/MEX

Tags: c, matlab, openmp, mex

I am learning `openmp` to use in a MATLAB `mex` file. However, I am not seeing any improvement in the result. I am purposely using three nested for-loops in this example since I need to approach similarly in my actual program later when I learn how to use `openmp` efficiently. My goal is to have a parallel function which takes pointers of type `double` to an array created by `mxMalloc`. This function will process these arrays accordingly.

```
#include <matrix.h> 
#include <mex.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <string.h>

void parallel( double *Ain, int nx, int ny, int nz, double *Aout);

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *in= mxGetPr( prhs[0] );

    mwSize ndim = mxGetNumberOfDimensions( prhs[0] );
    const mwSize *dims = mxGetDimensions( prhs[0] ); 
    int nx, ny, nz, nt;
    ny = dims[0];
    nx = dims[1];
    nz = dims[2];

    double *A = (double*) mxMalloc( ny*nx*nz*sizeof(double) );
    memcpy(A, in, ny*nx*nz*sizeof(double));

    const mwSize d[3] = {ny, nx, nz};
    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(3, d, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL );

    double *out = mxGetPr( plhs[0] );
    parallel(A, nx, ny, nz, out);

}

void parallel( double *Ain, int nx, int ny, int nz, double *Aout)
{
    int i, j, k;
    long long ijk;

    #pragma omp parallel for shared(Ain, nx, ny, nz, Aout) private(i, j, k, ijk) num_threads(8)
    for( k = 0; k < nz; k++ )
        for( j = 0; j < nx; j++ )
            for( i = 0; i < ny; i++ )
            {
                ijk = i + j*ny + k*nx*ny;
                Aout[ijk] = 2*Ain[ijk];
            }
}
```

Here is the compile command in Windows 64 bit as well as an example:

```
>> mex test_openmp.cpp COMPFLAGS="/openmp $COMPFLAGS"
>> tic,A = test_openmp(ones(500,500,500));toc
```

The result of the timing is as follows (on left is the number of threads and the right column is the time elapsed):

```
#threads   Time elapsed
_______________________
       1       1.287728
       2       1.213839
       3       1.238359
       4       1.257316
       5       1.252074
       6       1.268389
       7       1.265825
       8       1.278521
```

Could someone kindly tell me what I am missing that leads to such a terrible performance? Increasing the number of threads does not reduce the time elapsed. Does this mean that the function `parallel` is not the bottleneck of the computation?

When I try the following MATLAB command I get a very fast performance. Although I agree that there are other things in my code that are different from the following simple MATLAB command, ***I expected to see dramatic change in performance by increasing the number of threads***.

```
>> tic;A = 2*ones(500,500,500);toc;
Elapsed time is 0.380671 seconds.
>> A = ones(500,500,500); isa(A, 'double')
ans =
     1
```

I also tried `ones(1000,1000,1000)` in `test_openmp` and it takes `13.6` seconds on 8 threads while using `2*ones(1000,1000,1000)` takes only `2.8` seconds on my machine.

Comment: I don't have MATLAB at the moment. But could you verify if the datatype of `ones` is `uint8` or `double`?

Comment: It is of type `double` and I updated the question as well.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of the code, perhaps one misspelled as `parellel`, as how it is called in `mexFunction`, or is this just a typo for the question?  Also, why do you copy the `prhs[0]` data (the `memcpy` line)?  Performance is not far off without this...

Comment: It was just a typo, which is fixed now. I do this to mimic my actual code as I need to copy the input to some variables. How did you test the code without `memcpy`? One question: is there a multi-threaded `memcpy`?

Comment: I think for a fair comparison (with the benefits of multi-threading), startup MATLAB with `single-threaded` flag - http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabunix.html.

Comment: @LokeshA.R.: I still get very similar results after running MATLAB with `single-threaded` flag, i.e. `matlab -singleCompThread` and I get `1.227906` seconds to `0.364971` seconds on `ones(500,500,500)`.

Comment: I mean, why do you bother to make a copy of the data?  Why not pass `in` as the first argument to `parallel`?

Comment: I removed making a copy of the data but still MATLAB performs faster than my mex file using 8 threads (almost twice as fast).